# Split text in Pandas columns into different columns based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**I have Dataset like:**

```
df_raw.awards

0                               2 wins & 13 nominations.
1                                                    NaN
2      Nominated for 1 Golden Globe. Another 3 wins 
3                               5 wins & 10 nominations.
4      Nominated for 1 Oscar. Another 1 win & 7 nominations.
5       Won 1 Oscar. Another 46 wins & 71 nominations.
6                                       2 nominations.
7                                        1 nomination.
8                                                  NaN
9  Nominated for 2 Primetime Emmys. Another 4 wins & 7 nominations.
```

**What I want:**

1. Convert this column into different for each **Award** category

Count: win, nomination, and others into one category

Like

```
  win_count  Nomi_count  other_count  total_awards

0  2           13        0               15

1  nan         nan       nan             nan      
            
2  3            1        0               4

3  5           10        0               15

4  1            7        1                9

5  46          71        1              118
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is redundant and needs improvement, but it can be executed with the following code
Process flow: The

1. Delete unnecessary characters in the target string.
2. Add an id.
3. Transform the data to vertical
4. Check the existence of keywords in the target string and create a new column for the type.
5. Extract only the numbers in the target string and create a new column
6. Group and aggregate and add a total column.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

data = '''
awards
0 "2 wins & 13 nominations."
1 NaN
2 "Nominated for 1 Golden Globe. Another 3 wins" 
3 "5 wins & 10 nominations."
4 "Nominated for 1 Oscar. Another 1 win & 7 nominations."
5 "Won 1 Oscar. Another 46 wins & 71 nominations."
6 "2 nominations."
7 "1 nomination."
8 NaN
9 "Nominated for 2 Primetime Emmys. Another 4 wins & 7 nominations."
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep='\s+')

df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(' & ',',').str.replace('.',','))
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('Nominated for ', 'nominations.'))
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('Won', 'wins'))
df = df['awards'].str.split(',', expand=True)
tmp = ['actor_'+str(x) for x in df.index]
df['actor'] = tmp

df = df.loc[:,[0,1,2,'actor']]
df = df.melt('actor', var_name='awards')
df = df.fillna('')
df['awards'].loc[df['value'].str.contains('wins')] = 'win_count'
df['awards'].loc[df['value'].str.contains('nomination')] = 'Nomi_count'
df['awards'].loc[df['value'].str.contains('Another')] = 'other_count'
df['cnt'] = df['value'].str.extract('([0-9]+)')
df['cnt'] = df['cnt'].fillna(0).astype(int)
df = df.loc[:,['actor','awards','cnt']]

df = df.set_index('actor').groupby(['actor','awards'])['cnt'].sum().unstack().fillna(0)
df = df.loc[:,['win_count','Nomi_count','other_count']]

df
awards  win_count   Nomi_count  other_count total_awards
actor               
actor_0 2.0 13.0    0.0 15.0
actor_1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
actor_2 0.0 1.0 3.0 4.0
actor_3 5.0 10.0    0.0 15.0
actor_4 0.0 8.0 1.0 9.0
actor_5 1.0 71.0    46.0    118.0
actor_6 0.0 2.0 0.0 2.0
actor_7 0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0
actor_8 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
actor_9 0.0 9.0 4.0 13.0
```